# Modify object property in setState using unique id?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm trying to update an object property within an array based on a unique id property.
For example I have this in state:

```
const [speakers, setSpeakers] = useState([
    {
      id: nanoid(),
      name: "",
      title: "",
      position: "",
      description: ""
    }
  ])
```

I have a card, with a form in it, 3 text inputs, 1 textarea input, and the last piece is a field where I can upload a photo, crop it, get the base64 string, now I want to save this value in a photo property, inside the correct form. I created a "Add new speaker" button, and wrote some code that adds a new card (with the form), and also a delete button, which removes the specific card. All of that is working great, the whole point of my issue is that, after I crop the image, I want my state to look like this:

```
const [speakers, setSpeakers] = useState([
    {
      id: nanoid(),
      name: "",
      title: "",
      position: "",
      description: "",
      photo: "base64 string here"
    }
  ])
```

I know this is wrong, but I'm using the index, instead of the unique id, but this is what I have so far, that isn't working.

```
const getBase64Image = data => {
    imageRef.current.src = data
    let index = imageRef.current.id
    
    setSpeakers([
      {
        // object that we want to update
        ...speakers[index],
        photo: data // update the value of specific key
      }
    ])
  }
```

Just know that the `data`, is the base64 string. It works on the first try, but then if I add a second speaker/card/form, it removes the first object, and acts odd. Just to be clear, in the end, I should have/want this:

```
const [speakers, setSpeakers] = useState([
    {
      id: "123",
      name: "Bob",
      title: "",
      position: "",
      description: "",
      photo: "base64 string here"
    },
    {
      id: "456",
      name: "Peter",
      title: "",
      position: "",
      description: "",
      photo: "new base64 string here"
    },
    {
      id: "789",
      name: "Tim",
      title: "",
      position: "",
      description: "",
      photo: "new new base64 string here"
    },
  ])
```

Coming from Vue, new to React, thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current setState is only returning an array with one element.  You want to find the one with id === index, I think, and then add the photo prop to it, and leave the other array entries as they are.  You need to create a whole new object because of React's immutable rules.  So,

```
setSpeakers(curSpeakers => curSpeakers.map(s => 
  s.id === index ? {...s, photo: data} : s
));
```

Comment: Oh, only modify the one that I need to, it works! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

The way the code is written it will replace the entire contents of the array with the one entry that is being updated when `setState` is called. You will have to update the array in place ( shallow copy ) based on the index and then update the values in state.

**Existing code**

```
const getBase64Image = data => {
    imageRef.current.src = data
    let index = imageRef.current.id
    
    setSpeakers([
      {
        // object that we want to update
        ...speakers[index],
        photo: data // update the value of specific key
      }
    ])
  }
```

**Updated Code**

```
const getBase64Image = data => {
    imageRef.current.src = data;
    let indexToUpdate = imageRef.current.id;

    const updatedSpeakersData = speakers.map((speaker, index) => {
        const itemData = speakers[index];

        if(index === indexToUpdate) {
            return {
                ...itemData,
                photo: data
            }
        }

        return {
            ...itemData;
        }
    });
    
    setSpeakers(updatedSpeakersData)
  }
```